# Cannot create an instance of viewmodel class with hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, dagger-hilt

I am trying to create MVVM app using Openweathermap API and hilt. I tried to inject my repository into my viewmodel primary constractor and creating a ViewModelFactory class, in order to pass the parameters from viewmodel class to my main activity class it did not work with 'by viewmodels()' itself. Sadly it did not work and I am getting the following message "has no zero argument constructor". It worth to mention that I also tried to inject the repository into my secondary constractor.

**This is my MainActivity**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity
    @Inject constructor(var repository:WeatherRepositoryInterface) : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var previewAdapter: PreviewAdapter
    lateinit var viewModel:WeatherViewModel
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        initViewItems()
    }

    fun initViewItems() {
       viewModel= ViewModelProvider(this@MainActivity,FactoryViewModel(application,repository))[WeatherViewModel::class.java]
        binding.recyclerview.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
            previewAdapter = PreviewAdapter(viewModel.loadCities().value!!)
            previewAdapter.let {
                it.setOnItemClickListener(object: OnClickInterface{
                    override fun onClickItem(position: Int) {
                  var intent=Intent(this@MainActivity,DetailActivity::class.java)
                        intent.putExtra("name",viewModel.loadCities().value!![position].cityName)
                        intent.putExtra("img",viewModel.loadCities().value!![position].cityImg)
                        startActivity(intent)
                    }
                })
            }
            adapter = previewAdapter
     }
    }
}
```

**My ViewModel class**

```
@HiltViewModel
class WeatherViewModel @Inject constructor(application: Application, var repository: WeatherRepositoryInterface)
 : AndroidViewModel(application) ,LifecycleObserver{
companion object{
  private  val VIEWMODEL_STRING="WeatherViewModel.class"
}
private var list: MutableLiveData<List<Preview>> = MutableLiveData()
 fun getCityInfo(q:String) =
     liveData(Dispatchers.IO){
  emit(com.example.yourweatherapp.Resources.Resource.loading(data = null))
  try {
  emit(com.example.yourweatherapp.Resources.Resource.success(data = repository.getWeather(q=q)))
  } catch (e: Exception) {
   emit(e.message?.let { com.example.yourweatherapp.Resources.Resource.error(data = null, message = it) })
      e.message?.let { Log.e(VIEWMODEL_STRING, it) }
  }
 }

 fun loadCities():MutableLiveData<List<Preview>>{
  list.value= listOf(
Preview(
 CityList.santorini,
 CityList.santoriniImg),
Preview(CityList.bern,
CityList.bernImg),
Preview(CityList.venice,
CityList.veniceImg),
Preview("",CityList.myLocationImg)
  )
  return list
 }
}
```

**My ViewModelFactory class:**

```
class FactoryViewModel(
    var application:Application,
    var repository: WeatherRepositoryInterface
): ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory() {

    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T =
        WeatherViewModel(application,repository) as T
}
```

**My Gradle dependency file:**

```
plugins {
   id 'com.android.application'
   id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
   id 'kotlin-kapt'


}

android {
   compileSdk 31

   defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.example.yourweatherapp"
       minSdk 21
       targetSdk 31
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"

       testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
   }

   buildFeatures {
       dataBinding = true
       viewBinding = true
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
   }
   compileOptions {
       sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
       targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
   }
   kotlinOptions {
       jvmTarget = '1.8'
   }
}

dependencies {

   implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
   implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
   implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
   implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
   implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.0'
   implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.4.0'
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
   implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0"
   implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0"
   implementation("androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0")
   implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
   implementation("androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0")
   implementation("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1")
 //  implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.5.0-alpha01")

//http3
   implementation(platform("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-bom:4.9.3"))
   implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.0-alpha01"
   implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.1.0"
   implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp")
   implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor")

//lifecycle
   implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.0"

   implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0")
   implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.4.0")


   kapt("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.5.0-alpha01")
   implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.5.0-alpha01")
   implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:2.5.0-alpha01")
   

  //fragment
   implementation("androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.4.1")
   implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.1")
   implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.4.1")


   //hilt dagger
   implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.38.1")
   kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.38.1")
   //implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.4.2"
 implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0'
 implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0'
   implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03'
   kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0'


}

kapt {
   javacOptions {
       // These options are normally set automatically via the Hilt Gradle plugin, but we
       // set them manually to workaround a bug in the Kotlin 1.5.20
       option("-Adagger.fastInit=ENABLED")
       option("-Adagger.hilt.android.internal.disableAndroidSuperclassValidation=true")
   }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hilt ViewModel has no zero argument constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66197020/hilt-viewmodel-has-no-zero-argument-constructor)

Comment: Hey Andrew sadly it did not help I post here my gradle dependency file. Can you please tell me what missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove this line from your dependencies:

```
implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [this in migrations doc](https://github.com/google/dagger/releases/tag/dagger-2.34) and solved the issue for my case:

Remove this line from gradle:

```
implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03'
```

I'm using latest versions of all dependencies, make sure to check and apply all related and necessary migrations